# how to push subtitle from uitableview to detail view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i have a project which is basically a uitableview populated with a mutable array and has a search bar

now the uitableview has title and subtitle which are populated with different mutable arrays ..

when you tap on a cell (from the view or from the search view) it pushes the title to a new view controller.

i need the subtitle to be pushed also to the new view controller

i tried every thing i know but i had no success

i have attached the project so you can see how its coded and possibly tell me how to fix it

http://ezzati.net/KuwaitFood.zip

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign a identifier to the segue (the arrow from your table view controller to the new controller in your storyboard) and then use this function to grab the destination view controller and set it's property with the data you want to send:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier"])
    {
        SecondViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        // get the selected item index
        NSInteger index = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        // set the data property for the second view (pass data)
        vc.theProperty = [self.data objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Now you can find `theProperty` on your `SecondViewController` filled with data from the table view controller.

EDIT: I've reviewed your code. for your case do this:

in `-tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` change `self` to `indexPath` like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetail" sender:indexPath];
```

and in `prepareForSegue` do this:

```
DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

// get the selected item index
NSInteger index = ((NSIndexPath *)sender).row;

// index of searched object in self.objects
NSInteger trueIndex = [self.objects indexOfObject:[self.results objectAtIndex:index]];

// set the data property for the second view (pass data)
vc.detailLabelContents = [self.objects objectAtIndex:trueIndex];
vc.numberdetailLabelContents = [self.numbers objectAtIndex:trueIndex];
```

the problem was because you were using index of `self.results` and applying it to `self.objects` which was 0, so you were always getting the first object "You Tube"

Comment: ok i did what you said and it worked perfectly .. but when i search , if i select the first cell from the filtered selection it shows the first cell from the non filtered selection..

Comment: i think i didn't explain well ... here is an updated copy of the project http://ezzati.net/KuwaitFoodupdate.zip .. run it and search for amazon for example and select it and see what happens.. it shows  youtube instead

Comment: can you please send me the project file edited because i didn't work with me .. it crashes when i select the filtered cell..

Comment: now searching work perfectly but selecting a row  without searching crashes the app ... i know i bothered you so much but bare with a newbie please :-)

Comment: hmm, this is because you've used two different tableviews. one for search and one for main. check this: http://cl.ly/US3C

Answer (score 3):

Please replace the function below.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetail"]) {
        NSString *object = nil;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

        if (self.searchDisplayController.isActive) {
            indexPath = [[self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView] indexPathForSelectedRow];
            object = self.results[indexPath.row];
        } else {
            indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
        }

        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailLabelContents:object];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setNumberdetailLabelContents:[sender detailTextLabel].text];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the last line of

`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

as below

```
[[segue destinationViewController] setDetailLabelContents:[sender detailTextLabel].text];
```